# Lots of errors when creating a new project

Tags: android, project, new-operator

When I create a new project with Android studio I have a lot of weird errors. The project is completely new, I don't do anything, I simply try to run it and it doesn't work.

For example, it tells me there's no default activity, I go into the "Edit configuration" menu, change to "Specified Activity", choose the new activity that was created. Still an error, it tells me I need to declare it in the androidManifest. But it already is.
If I try to recompile the project it tells me I have some errors with colors.xml (in the res folder). The file is incomplete. If I fix it I have issues with other xml files. For example res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher_round.xml contains code coming from another project!

The code in colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
    <component name="AndroidLayouts">
        <shared>
            <config />
        </shared>
    </component>
    <component name="AndroidLogFilters">
        <option n
```

The code in the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fmahieu.androidtestquiz">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with Gradle. Just sync and rebuild your app. Also do file->cache restart. It should compile fine. Check your app gradle file to see if there are version conflicts.

Comment: I actually reinstalled android studio. Still had some issues, did a sync and it worked! thanks!